# GPG can't decrypt: no pinentry program

Tags: gpg, pinentry

I can't decrypt my passwords with `pass` neither with
`gpg` directly.

```
gpg: encrypted with rsa4096 key, ID id, created creation_date
      "name <email>"
      gpg: public key decryption failed: No pinentry
      gpg: decryption failed: No pinentry
```

It does not show a prompt dialog asking for the master password.

It says "no pinentry" but the program is installed:

```
$ ls /usr/bin/pinentry*
/usr/bin/pinentry
/usr/bin/pinentry-curses
/usr/bin/pinentry-emacs
/usr/bin/pinentry-gnome3
/usr/bin/pinentry-gtk-2
/usr/bin/pinentry-qt
/usr/bin/pinentry-tty
```

Please, I need help asap because I can't login into nothing without
my passwords, which are all encrypted with GPG.

Comment: Quite a wild guess, but the issue might be in the configuration of your `gpg-agent`. You may be able to work around it with `gpg ... --pinentry-mode=loopback ...`. A complete answer will likely require more information about your system: which OS are you using? Which version of gnupg? Is there any reference to `pinentry` in your `gpg.conf` or `gpg-agent.conf`? How is `gpg-agent` activated?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help. So, what I ended up doing was this: `pkill gpg-agent` followed by `gpg-agent --pinentry-program=/usr/bin/pinentry-gtk-2 --daemon` and it worked. I don't know id hadn't worked before, but glad I was able to solve it...

Comment: Not explicitly mentioned here, but I got `no pinentry` message when using pinentry-dmenu, with `pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-dmenu` in `$HOME/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` and while having no _pinentry-dmenu.conf_ file. Using `>$HOME/.gnupg/pinentry-dmenu.conf` to create empty _pinentry-dmenu.conf_ solved the problem for me. It seems that if, for whatever reason the pinentry program errors out, it causes this error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solved the problem by running the following commands

```bsh
pkill gpg-agent
gpg-agent --pinentry-program=/usr/bin/pinentry-gtk-2 --daemon
```

and it worked. I don't know why pinentry wasn't working, but starting
a new gpg-agent daemon has worked.

Comment: Same thing can happen on a Mac (for reasons not yet understood by me); this solution is helpful on MacOS, too.

Comment: I can confirm, it is useful for macos too but slightly different:
`gpg-agent --pinentry-program=/usr/local/bin/pinentry --daemon`

Comment: thanks for this answer! I needed first to figure out which pinentry software is available on my system. For that I used `ls -l /usr/bin/pinentry*`

Comment: On Fedora 38 with Gnome 44 it was enugh to just pkill gpg-agent, then running pass (gpg password manager) automatically spawned the gnome pinentry like normal.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error because I had pinentry-qt configured in my ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf but did not have qt installed. Choosing a different pinentry solved the issue.